# ngbTypeahead search results missing

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am currently writing an [ngbTypeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api) search and I am stuck because I have never really worked with Observables, which are the expected return type of the [ngbTypeahead search](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#basic).

The search function in my component looks like this:

```js
  search: OperatorFunction<string,  readonly LoqateResponseModel[]> = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
return text$.pipe(
  switchMap(term => this.addressService.searchAddress(term, this.countryCode)),
  map(results => {
    const searchResults = results[LoqateKeyEnum.ITEMS] as [];
    const searchResultLoqateModels: LoqateResponseModel[] = [];
    searchResults.forEach(result => {
      searchResultLoqateModels.push(new LoqateResponseModel(
        result[LoqateKeyEnum.ID],
        result[LoqateKeyEnum.TYPE],
        result[LoqateKeyEnum.TEXT],
        result[LoqateKeyEnum.HIGHLIGHT],
        result[LoqateKeyEnum.DESCRIPTION]));
    });
    return searchResultLoqateModels;
  })
);
```

}

```
resultFormatter = (loqateResponse: LoqateResponseModel): string => loqateResponse.display();
```

I am conducting a loqate search and am storing the results as model objects in a list and return them.

```js
public searchAddress(searchValue, countryCode): Observable<object> 
  {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams();
    return this.httpClient.post(this.addressSearchUrl, {}, {
      headers: this.headers,
      params: new HttpParams()
        .set('Key', loqateKey)
        .set('Text', searchValue)
        .set('Origin', countryCode)
    });
  }
```

The Model looks like this:

```js
export class LoqateResponseModel {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public type: LoqateTypeEnum,
    public text: string,
    public highlight: string,
    public description: string) {
  }

  public isAddress(): boolean { return this.type === LoqateTypeEnum.ADDRESS; }
  public display(): string { return this.text + ', ' + this.description; }
}
```

Now I thought, that a list of `LoqateResponseModels` is stored as result of the `search` and then each of these list items are being formatted properly to display in the typeahead popup through the `resultFormatter`.

tldr: I want to search something with the ngbTypeahead and query the search term from an API endpoint and display the search results in the typeahead popup.

**Edit**: I've edited the answer, this code is working.

Comment: Can you please specify what is working and what is not working.  I don't understand exactly what the issue is.

Comment: I've edited my code to remove misleading code. I have an ngbTypeahead where a user should be able to search an address. He types in a few characters and the search function is called. In the search function I want to call an API that returns search results. I need to subscribe to those search results and still return an OperatorFunction because that is ngbTypeaheads requirement. I really can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).  This operator will subscribe you an observable source and emit its results:

You don't want to `return null`, you simply return the observable with your piped modification.

Your operator function should take an observable and return an observable.  Your observable can simply use `switchMap` to map the incoming `text` to the api call.

```js
search: OperatorFunction<string, readonly LoqateResponseModel[]> = text$ => 
    text$.pipe(
        switchMap(text => this.searchAddress(text))
    );
```

Each time `switchMap` receives some `text`, it will do a few things for you:

1. subscribe to `searchAddress(text)`
2. emit results from this subscription
3. stop emitting results from previous subscriptions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question with the code you provided, but it doesn't show any search suggestions. I want to transform the json response items into loqate model instances and save those in my Observable so that I can use them for later. And in order to display a readable string I use the resultFormatter. It just doesn't work as expected though... The reason why I need to store the models and not strings in the returned observable is because I need to access the loqate models ID later on when the user selects a search suggestion

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Can you tell if the call to `addressService.searchAddress()` actually being executed?

Comment: There are no errors. You are right, it is not being executed. But why though

Comment: It doen't look like your are acutally using the resultFormatter. You can further modify your stream by applying the `resultFormatter`, which might be all you need to do.  I'm not familar with the ngb stuff or the Loqate stuff.

Comment: I now know why, it says: `Type (text$: Observable<string>) => void is not assignable to type (text: Observable<string>) => Observable<readonly any[]>`

Comment: oh, there you go!  looks like you need to add a `return` or remove the surrounding `{}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230553/discussion-between-bojack-horseman-and-bizzybob).